# Gradle. Kotlin - is it possible to create dynamic ("on fly") tasks?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm an android developer. And as result write build by Gradle. Many tasks I write on Gradle DSL on Groovy.

Sometimes I need to create Gradle tasks dynamically ("on fly"). Here example:

```
task installDebugFlavors() {
    android.applicationVariants.all { v ->
        if (v.name.endsWith('Debug')) {
            String name = v.name.capitalize()
            dependsOn "install$name"
        }
    }
}
```

This task generate new tasks with all flavors combinations.
As result Gradle script is very small, easy to understand and easy to support. It' very powerfull Groovy capability. And it's very often help me.

In new version of Gradle was introduce new language - Kotlin.

My question is: Is it possible to write same task (for dynamic creation of another tasks) on Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create tasks dynamically and refer to other tasks by (String) name in the Gradle Kotlin DSL.

```kotlin
tasks {
    "installDebugFlavors" {
        android.applicationVariants.forEach { v ->
            if (v.name.endsWith("Debug")) {
                val name = v.name.capitalize()
                dependsOn("install$name")
            }
        }
    }        
}
```